# How to get different Centrality indexes of each node from a Neo4j Graph?

Tags: java, graph, social-networking, neo4j, sna

I am working on a great project on social network analysis. My objective is to get different centrality indexes for each node in a graph. I need to analyze the graph and derive some meaning full information from it. I am using Neo4J graph database(Community Edition 1.8.M06) for this project. And I am very new to Neo4J, just two weeks of experience.

Right now my graph is a friendship graph, and so the only relationship I have in the graph is of Friendship, which is mutual. The graph is undirected, unweighted and simplex. Soon I'll be adding other relationships and objects into the graph, which will make it complex.

I understand Neo4J has implementations for a range graph algorithms to measure Centrality and I got that information from this [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.neo4j/neo4j-graph-algo/1.8.M01/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl/centrality/EigenvectorCentrality.java#EigenvectorCentrality). But I couldn't find any information or examples on how to use them for getting the centrality measures. I also understand these algorithms are [not production ready](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j-graph-algo/1.8.M06/).

Is there anyone who have tried out something similar with Neo4J? Is it possible to do it just using Neo4J? If not can I use R programming language to get Centrality indexes from Neo4J?

I'd tried  using R with igraph package to get centrality from an edge-list. I suppose I could use R to access Neo4J using the REST API.

I had also found some examples on using the common Graph Algorithms for [shortest path problems](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/tutorials-java-embedded-graph-algo.html). But no direct examples for getting the Centrality indexes. Learning from an example seems to be a perfect idea.

Thanks,
Deepu

Answer (score 1):

The centrality algos are not used as much as the shortest path ones, but you should be able to test them. The main characteristic with them is that they might get slower as your graph grows, since they need exhaustive traversals. How big is your graph?

Comment: My graph is fairly small, just nearly 2900 nodes and 4000 edges. I just want to test the built in centrality algorithms. How do I test them? Or can we use R to analyze Neo4J graph?

Comment: You could use R, or just import your graph as an node/edge list and do a small java program? https://github.com/jexp/batch-import